# Can I automatically hide a program in the taskbar on startup?

Tags: windows, boot, taskbar, notification-area

I have a Windows application that I need to run on startup and keep running continually. It spawns a window, and I don't need that window open all the time. Rather than just minimize it, I wanted to actually hide it in the system tray. For that, I downloaded a little program called [HideIt](http://vasanrulez.deviantart.com/art/HideIt-Hide-all-your-windows-206517834), which can hide things to the system tray. However, you have to manually click on things in order to hide it; it's not automated. I would like to automate things.

On the other hand, I could add the `/MINIMIZED` command line argument to the startup shortcut, and that would start the program minimized. But that's only halfway there... it still wouldn't be in the system tray.

Know of any way to accomplish this? Any programs I can download to do this?

Comment: This would require you write a small tool yourself.  Unless you are programmer your unlikely to find an tool with your percise requirements.

Comment: There are lots of AutoHotkey scripts available already for minimising apps to the tray. It shouldn't be hard to edit them to first launch your app and then minimise it.